# A quite classic differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

> Find all the derivable functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $k \in \mathbb{R_+}$ exists with $$F(x)+kf'(x) = 0$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $F$ is the primitive of $f$ with $F(0) = 0$.

---

This seems to be quite a classic problem, however, I couldn't find a solution yet. I tried constructing $(e^xF(x))'$ or $(e^{-x}F(x))'$ type expressions, but with no success. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Does it look more familiar with you write it as $y'' + (1/k) y = 0$?

Comment: Can you expand a bit more?

Comment: $y'' + \omega^2 y = 0$ is a well known ODE, the solutions are the linear combinations of $ \sin(\omega x) $ and $\cos(\omega x)$. Compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know of this type of equation! Since you made me curious, is $y'' = ky$, where $k > 0$, also a known ODE?

Comment: All linear differential equations with constant coefficients are “easily” solvable, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients, and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Second-order_case for the second-order case.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the references!

Comment: Please define "derivable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the initial condition $F(0)=0,$ you have essentially defined $$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t,$$ so $$\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t+kf'(x)=0$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$ In differentiating, this results in the equation $$f(x)+kf''(x)=0$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$ There are two cases to consider here. One case is $k=0.$ If so, then trivially, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$ The other case is $k\neq0,$ in which case $$f''(x)+\frac1{k}f(x)=0$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$ This equation can be rewritten as $$f''(x)-\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}f'(x)+\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}f'(x)+\frac1{\sqrt{k}^2}f(x)=\left[f'-\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}f\right]'(x)+\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}\left[f'-\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}f\right](x),$$ so letting $g=f'-\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}f$ reduces the equation to $$g'(x)+\frac{i}{\sqrt{k}}g(x)=0,$$ and this equation is separable. Once you solve it, the equation for $f$ can be solved using the integration factor. Anyway, the general solution can be written as $$f(x)=C_0\cos\left(\frac1{\sqrt{k}}x\right)+C_1\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt{k}}x\right)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R},$ and this works even if $k\lt0,$ though it will just make the expression look awkward.

Comment: Thank you for the proof!